# Move camera along with marker

Tags: java, android

```
fresh.setOnMarkerDragListener(new GoogleMap.OnMarkerDragListener() {
            @Override
            public void onMarkerDragStart(Marker marker) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onMarkerDrag(Marker marker) {
               fresh.moveCamera( CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(marker.getPosition(),15.0f));

            }

            @Override
            public void onMarkerDragEnd(Marker marker) {

            }
        });
```

iam trying to move my map camera when my location of the marker changes , which i expect that will smooth animation but unfourtunatly the performonce was very rashy and when i tocuhed the marker and move it it went to south africa , which were in india

Comment: Use interpolation to smooth out the movement.

Comment: How to use it help me with the code  @Steven

Answer (score 0):

Can't help you with your specific case as I do not have your code but this is the general idea. You take your current position (where the camera is) and you get the desired position (where the marker is). You use something called a value animator

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/animation/ValueAnimator

to animate the position of your camera using the current and the desired position. The value animator does the interpolation for you but you will have to set the properties which you want animated.